# Danger posed by alpha particles

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

If a sheet of paper can shield alpha particles, why are they at all harmful to us, 'cause they may even get shielded before passing through the skin?

Comment: The alpha source may be ingested and then cells which can be affected by alpha particles would be within the range of the alpha particles.

Comment: Yeah, I think that the danger with alpha radiation isn't so much external exposure since alpha particles can be blocked by outer layers of the skin. The real problem is inhalation or ingestion of an alpha-emitter, which can result in much more damage to important tissues by alpha radiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha particles are very strongly ionizing, so they are extremely good at damaging biological material.  Because they do not penetrate skin alpha emitters are not very dangerous *unless they are ingested*, when they are extremely dangerous as they then get into intimate contact with your lungs, stomach and, if digested, the rest of you. 'Ingested' means eaten, drunk, or in particular breathed in, so any alpha emitter which is a gas or dust is very bad news indeed.

('Not very dangerous': I suppose you could get burns and/or skin cancer from them even if not ingested.)